# Privileged access to spotify web api or database export?

Tags: api, spotify

I'm working on my bachelor thesis which is a spotify app that uses my webservice for music recommendation based on tags (lastfm). To build a webservice that responds in realtime i need to precompute the similarities between tracks/artists/albums and store them locally. Unfortunately the spotify web api allows only 10 requests per second which really slows down the whole data aquisition process.

Therefore I'm asking if there is a way to get a privileged access to the web api or to get some kind of database export in the form of a *.csv file that contains spotify-ids and titles/names?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping the Spotify database in this manner is actually against the Spotify API Terms of Service, and it's one of the reasons this rate limit is in place.

You might want to try [The Echo Nest](http://echonest.com) — their APIs might be more suited to the sort of thing you're doing.